# Adding a string to a nested array using push MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hey I want to add a string to a nested array using push function with MongoDB in Api NodeJS.

```
router.post('/add-member-to-card', (req, res) => {

    Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.idBoard }, 
        {
            "$push": { ['lists.' + req.body.indexList + '.cards.' + req.body.indexCard + '.members'] : { $each: req.body.member, $position: 0 }   }, 
            "$push": { "activity" : { $each: [req.body.activity], $position: 0 }   }, 
        },
            { upsert: true },
        ((err, updated) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            else { 
                console.log(req.body.member);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Second push is working, but with first is something wrong. generally, I'm trying to do it, maybe it can not be done like that? I mean adding items to an embedded array?

Container of req.body.member is -> da7sda68ds6ad87asd68da

> edit

I took to first $push with :

```
// "$set": { ['lists.' + req.body.indexList + '.cards.' + req.body.indexCard + '.members']: req.body.members },
```

It work /\

Comment: Care to show us an example document from the `Board` model?

Comment: Could you look edit? u still need board example??

Comment: I meant the schema definition for Board model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is you have multiple definitions for field `$push`. That's the same as having:

```
let foo = {
    a: 1,
    a: 2
};
```

Try writing it as:

```
{
    $push: {
           ['lists.' + ... + '.members'] : { $each: req.body.member, $position: 0 },
           "activity" : { $each: [req.body.activity], $position: 0 } 
       },
  }
```

Maybe that will help